# Dropdownlist folder files php

Tags: php, xml

Please, i need help, how can i load folder files which i uploader just before in a directory, into a dropdownlist on PHP???

Now i have this code, but doesnt work...

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <select name="seleccionArchivo">
            <?php
                $dir = $_GET["/Repositorio"];

                $files = scandir($dir);

                // Prepare the select box to echo
                echo "<select name=\"files\">";

                foreach ($files as $file)
                {
                // Return files only
                if ( is_file($dir. $file) )
                echo "<option value=\"$file\">$file</option>";
                }

                echo "</select>";
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Ir al examen">
    </form>
```

Comment: Does it print errors? If so, please share them.

Comment: It is very dangerous to allow GET parameters to directly list any files on disk back for the user.  Filter to certain dirs or set a base dir to work from.

Comment: Change `$dir = $_GET["/Repositorio"];` to `$dir = $_GET["Repositorio"];`

Comment: this code is found looking for on Internet. I need a suggest because i have no idea about PHP. can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the echo "" within the PHP script.  You have that select within your other select.  In the code it is looking like this:

```
<select name="seleccionArchivo">
    <select name=\"files\"><option>...</option></select>
</select>
```

When it should just be:

```
<select name="selecctionArchivo">
    <option value="File 1">File 1</option>...<option value="File n">File n</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can i do that?. I dont understand what you try to say me